# react native this.refs.nav is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native

new to react native, trying to render the main page with a button on the navigation to go the user page.

```
var TourChampIOs = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
       ....
    },

    componentWillMount() {

        ....
    },

    _handleUserDataPress: function() {

        // Get by ref not prop
        this.refs.nav.push({
            component: UserPage,
            title: 'User Page'
        });
    },    
   render: function() {

                return <NavigatorIOS
                    style={styles.container}
                    initialRoute={{
                        title: 'Tour Champ',
                        component: ThemeList,
                        rightButtonTitle: tc.user.displayName.split(' ')[0],
                        onRightButtonPress: this._handleUserDataPress
                    }}/>;

        }
```

the error i'm getting is 
`Error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to assign a ref attribute to your component when returned from render and give "nav" as its value

```
   render: function() {

                return <NavigatorIOS
                    ref="nav" // Here is the change
                    style={styles.container}
                    initialRoute={{
                        title: 'Tour Champ',
                        component: ThemeList,
                        rightButtonTitle: tc.user.displayName.split(' ')[0],
                        onRightButtonPress: this._handleUserDataPress
                    }}/>;

        }
```

Comment: not following you. can you paste in the sample code?

Comment: you really should not post code in comments, why not edit your answer instead?

Comment: seems like @François 's answer supersedes mine - have a look at this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions

Comment: I wondering why I got 2 down vote. Did I wrote something stupid ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do and if the use of refs is really adapted to what you want. I certainly would not use ref as a way to stock a reference of the page you want to go onclick.

I you still choose to do this ugly thing, just put the ref in the rendering function:
     Click This!

retrieve the ref in the handleClick function

```
handleClick = function() {
    doSomethingWithThisref(this.refs.UserPage);
    // or
    // set a new state for this component
    this.setState({someState:"somedata", function() {
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.UserPage);
    });
}
```

ref is used to have a reference to the DOM instead of the virtual DOM returned by React render function.
Here is a good example : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

By the way you can't access this.refs because you probably didn't set any ref in the render function. But, in my opinion, you shouldn't set refs dynamically with an handler but in the render function.

Hope it helps

Comment: Anyone could explain to me why I received down vote ? Did I write something stupid ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the people down vote you only saw the ugly thing, didn't see you said that's not recommended.

Comment: Ahh, BTW, if you don't want the down vote record you can simply delete your answer... I did this the last time I receive down vote..